# openssl_encrypt last Bytes are wrong

Tags: php, encryption

I'm having trouble with `openssl_encrypt`. The last 8 Bytes seem to be erroneous. When I compare my encrypted string to that of an online tool (http://des.online-domain-tools.com/link/bf9973gpgFBNsITuh/), they are strictly identical except for the last 8 bytes. With AES, the last 16 Bytes will be different.

Can someone explain the difference? Any help will be most welcomed.

The PHP code:

```
$method = 'DES-CBC';
$cipherKey = 'CsflsUHV';
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length($method));
$iv = $iv ^ $iv; // this will ensure an IV composed of zeroes only
$plainText = 'This is my plain text to encrypt.';
echo implode(' ', str_split(bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $method, $cipherKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv)), 2));
```

The results (top is PHP, bottom is des.online-domain-tools.com):

```
9f 47 5d 8b 7d c3 4b 55 96 b9 27 86 c2 e8 d1 fc 68 7d 6e 83 49 fa 3b af 04 73 da e8 c8 3c a4 bc 3a 94 c8 c3 ab e6 36 22

9f 47 5d 8b 7d c3 4b 55 96 b9 27 86 c2 e8 d1 fc 68 7d 6e 83 49 fa 3b af 04 73 da e8 c8 3c a4 bc e6 6d 49 c9 3d 44 ca e7
```

**Note**: I know that DES is obsolete and that the IV should not be zeros, but this is a simple example to understand what is going wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's the [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)). Why do you need code that works in the same way like some online tool?

Comment: make sure both your work and the online tool uses same padding, set the pad to PKCS5 or either do it yourself

Comment: You'll notice your online tool will happily decrypt the data from your PHP code.

Comment: Ok, it was indeed padding, thanks guys.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Because this online tool do provide the same output than the real system I'm working with.